# which servlets are not part of Web application

Tags: java, servlets

Servlet specification SRV.3.2 says

> Servlets in a container that were not deployed as part of aWeb
>   application are implicitly part of a “default” Web application and
>   have a default ServletContext.

so how can we create serlvets those are not part of web application and what is the use of them?

Comment: The container implements them for you. For example, the default servlet which serves static resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at section SRV.9.1:

> **SRV.9.1 Web Applications Within Web Servers**
>
> A web application is rooted at a specific path within a web server. For
>   example, a catalog application could be located at
>   http://www.example.com/catalog. All requests that start with this prefix will be routed to the
>   ServletContext which represents the catalog application.

Servlets that are not part of a web application are therefore servlets that are not rooted at a specific path. In other words, they're rooted at the `/` path, and their use is to serve content from there.

Note that this is pretty awkward to begin with (as the verbose text already shows), so most web application servers let you designate an application to run at the 'root' context path in some other way.